# Cannot communicate with github server

Tags: plasticscm

I have installed plastic v5.0.44.618. I'm using server and client services in my local PC. I've created a repository on github for synchronizing with plasticSCM.

I have my workspace and i modify a file (txt file) and add it into source control.

When i try "Replicate - Sync with Git..." i put my Repository URL, User and PassWord and finally "Sync button"

I get this error (View Image)

Thanks for the help!
[image: Error trying to sync with GitHub]

Comment: Is it a public repo? I would like to test the sync operation. In case it´s private, could you hide the user/pass, but show a sceenshot of the entered Github address?

Comment: Thanks! The repo it's public. Here's the URL. https://github.com/Irwin1985/sc.git

Comment: Which protocol are you using? Could you write the exact URL that you are setting in the 'Repository URL' field??

Comment: The Repository URL is: https : // github . com / Irwin1985/sc.git [Without any spaces, the editor modifies the URL]